# Visual Studio 2015 can't update Internet explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, internet-explorer, visual-studio-2015

I use Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10. 
I have installed "Internet Explorer 11" on my system, In my C# project WebBrowser is Internet Explorer 7, how that is possible?
On previous versions Visual Studio, if i update Internet Explorer its automatic update on my visual studio project.

I only can choose Browser in ASP.NET application. 
I work in C# applicaton which include Web Browser!

How fix this problem?

Comment: There is an option to add a browser [Link here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudioWebDevelopmentTipAddChromeIncognitoModeAsABrowser.aspx). You can browse the path and add the brwoser

Comment: In the tool bar next to the browser, there should be a down arrow where you can select Browse With and add/remove entries in the emulator list or change the default.

Comment: I use project C# desktop application, I don't have option to choose Web Browser when I want debug

Answer (score 0):

Without doubt, the answer to this question is that you are running Windows 10. Internet Explorer has been sunset and replaced with Microsoft Edge, so even if you choose to keep Internet Explorer on your machine, it is very likely that Microsoft no longer supports the same "updating" features it once did for that product.

However, there is a not-so-ideal workaround, and that is to use the ActiveX control for IE 11.